# Как убрать eventHandler с кнопки в javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse

```
Scene scene = this.root.getScene();

scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> gameManager.restartGame(event));
scene.removeEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> gameManager.restartGame(event));
```

при таком коде во время запуска игры по идее должно пропадать действие при нажатии кнопки. Без добавления eventHandler игра не реагирует, но вот убрать его она не дает. Что может быть не так ?

scene и stage всегда остаются теми же

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно зачем убирать обработчик, сразу после того как Вы его добавили. Ну да ладно, Бог Вам судья. А если серьезно, то Вам надо хэндлер создать отдельно, т.е. не лямбдой его передавать, а прям создать объект EventHandler.

```
EventHandler<KeyEvent> handler = new EventHadler<>() {
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
       gameManager.restartGame(event);
    }
};
scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, handler);
scene.removeEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, handler);
```

Я не уверен на 100%, но думаю сие поведение обусловлено именно тем, что при передаче обработчиков лямбдой, Вы получаете два разных объекта. Соответственно удаление становится проблематичным, т.к. мы не знаем какой именно хэндлер надо удалить. Когда у нас объект хэндлера будет один - мы сможем однозначно его идентифицировать и удалить.

Comment: Суть в том, что мне нужно проверить, чтобы оно работало нормально. Т.е. Добавляло и убирало.
Пытался сделать следующее:

`EventHandler<KeyEvent> restartGameHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() { 
            @Override 
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) { 
             restartGame(event);
            }
        };`

А сами хендлеры призываются в другом классе. При этом все крашится и кричит, что что-то не так

Comment: @xxxlota Вы хотите протестировать стандартную библиотеку? Будьте уверены, если все делать правильно (как я описал), то все будет работать. Иначе оно бы не пошло в релиз. Для лучшего понимания проблемы предоставьте рабочий код, или stacktarce ошибки, иначе трудно разобраться, что же все-таки не так.

Comment: уже закончил с этой частью, разобрался, спасибо